# How to write unit test case for generic repository pattern in .net core

Tags: c#, nunit, moq, dbset

Hi I am trying to write nunit test case for generic repository pattern methods.
Below is my method in dbrepository.

```cs
public class DbRepository<T> : BaseRepository, IDbRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public DbRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        dbSet = dbContext?.Set<T>();
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = this.dbSet;
        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
        {
            query = query.Include(include);
        }

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }

        return await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Then I planned to use FakeDbSet as below. I have little confusion here. I found one example in github https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/GenericRepository/blob/master/tests/GenericRepository.EntityFramework.Test/Infrastrucure/FakeDbSet.cs here they have some methods. In fakedbset do we need to write exact same methods there in my dbrepositry? Below is my fakedbset class

```cs
public class FakeDbSet<T> : DbSet<T> where T : class
{
    ObservableCollection<T> _data;
    IQueryable _query;
    public FakeDbSet()
    {
        _data = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        _query = _data.AsQueryable();
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _query;
        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
        {
            query = query.Include(include);
        }

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }

        return await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

In the above code, I added same method GetAsync which was there in dbrepository but in above method code

> IQueryable query = _query; which gives error cannot implicitly convert type system.linq.Iqueryable to system.linq.Iqueryable .

Then I wrote my one of the test

```cs
[Test]
public void TestGetAsync()
{
    //Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<OrdersRequestContext>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.Set<OrdersRequestContext>())
        .Returns(new FakeDbSet<OrderDetails>
        {
            new OrderDetails{ OrderDetailsId = 6}
        });
    var entityRepository = new DbRepository<OrderDetails>(mock.Object);
    var orders = entityRepository.GetAsync();
}
```

I couldnt run this test because of the above error I stated. Also I want to know Fakedbset methods should be same as my dbrepository methods? I am facing error in  IQueryable query = _query; as I mentioned. So I am missing something in the way I am doing so can someone help me to correct this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you using .NET Fw or .NET Core? Please also share with us which version.

Comment: Hi Peter I am using .net core

Comment: What version of. NET Core are you using?

Comment: hi Peter I am using dotnetcore 3.1

Comment: I suggest to try to utilize one of these packages: [EntityFrameworkCore3Mock](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core3-mock),[EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing). These can make the database mocking quite easy.

Comment: Just a note: Entity Framework is *already* a generic repository; adding a generic repository on top of a generic repository usually doesn't gain you anything. And EF is already tested.